# Silverlight Isolated Storage using only Javascript API

Tags: javascript, silverlight, isolatedstorage

I did some online research and it seems like Isolated Storage is only accessible with managed Silverlight code.  Just to confirm that I didn't miss anything, is there a way to access Isolated Storage in Silverlight using only **unmanaged** [Javascript API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903928%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can call Silverlight methods from javascript and vice versa as described here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav

So you should be able to return something from your Silverlight apps isolated storage.

Comment: This requires managed code. I am looking for a pure unmanaged solution.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered your own question before you asked it, but for the sake of affirmation:

**IsolatedStorage cannot be directly accessed with Javascript, only with managed code**

Is your aversion to using managed code do to a restriction imposed on you, or because you don't want to (or don't know how to) write managed code?

If it's the latter, check out [BakedGoods](https://github.com/klawson88/Baked-Goods). Its a Javascript library that establishes a uniform interface that can be used to conduct common storage operations in all native, and some non-native storage facilities, including IsolatedStorage (which it accesses via complementary managed code).

With it, placing data in IsolatedStorage can be accomplished with code as simple as:

```
bakedGoods.set({
    data: [{key: "key", value: "value"}],
    storageTypes: ["silverlight"],
    complete: function(byStorageTypeRemovedItemKeysObj, byStorageTypeErrorObj){/*code*/}
});
```

Retrieving and removing data is just as easy. Trust me on all of this, I would know; i'm its maintainer :) .